# My Delete Servlet doesn't delete from the database

Tags: jsp, servlets, server-side

I have a delete album DAO, a delete album class and a delete servlet all connected to a database but it still doesn't run the query, i.e it doesn't work.

The below code is for the delete servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        DeleteAlbum Album = new DeleteAlbum(name) ;

        AlbumDAO.INSTANCE.delete(Album);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

This is the delete album class

```
        public class DeleteAlbum {
            String name ;

            public DeleteAlbum(String name){
                super();

                this.name = name;
            }
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

        }
```

And this section of code connects to the database

```
public enum DeleteAlbumDAO {
        INSTANCE;

        public Connection getConnection() {
            Connection con = null ;
            try {
                Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/oneDB", "sa", "");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return con ;
        }

        public void delete(Album name)  {       
            try {
                Connection con = getConnection() ;
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate("Delete from ALBUM WHERE name="+name+"");
                System.out.println("Connection Succesful");
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And this is code for the original ALBUM DAO, I'm trying to delete album by name, I added albumDAO to test if ti was connected but it still isn't working

```
import model.Album;
import model.DeleteAlbum;

public enum AlbumDAO {
    INSTANCE;

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null ;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/oneDB", "sa", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return con ;
    }

    public void save(Album album) {     
        try {
            Connection con = getConnection() ;
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ALBUM (name, artist , genre)"
                        + "VALUES ('" + album.getName() + "','"+ album.getArtist() + "','"+ album.getGenre() + "')");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void delete(DeleteAlbum name)  {     
        try {
            Connection con = getConnection() ;
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("Delete from ALBUM WHERE name="+name+"");
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't delete from my database

Comment: `stmt.executeUpdate("Delete from ALBUM WHERE name="+name+"");` the  `name` here is the `Album` object. You may need to accept the `DeleteAlbum` and call `album.getName()`.

Comment: And you really, really need to learn about prepared statements and parameters: you forgot the quotes around the name, and even if you hadn't forgotten them, the statement would still fail if the album name contains a quote. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: You also need to learn about exception handling, BTW. Catching the exceptions like you're doing is a bad idea: you're hiding the problem from the user. If I insert an album, and it fails, I want to know it by getting an exception, and not proceed as if the insert succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT actually passing the alubum name to the prepared statement, so you need to change the `delete` method as shown below:

```
public void delete(DeleteAlbum album)  {     
        //Use try with resources as shown below which closes conn & stmt objects
        try(Connection con = getConnection() ;
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("Delete from ALBUM WHERE name=?")) {

            stmt.setString(1, album.getName());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please use the preparedstament setString(), setInt(), etc..  methods in order to avoid the [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Also, ensure that you are using [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) or closing resources in the finally block in order to avoid the connection leaks.

Comment: Your SQL is invalid, and it promotes the use of string concatenation to pass parameters. Read my comment on the question.

Comment: @JBNizet I am just editing the question to suggest the same

Comment: Yes, but take some more time. Your code wouldn't compile. You need a prepared statement. executeUpdate() should be called without any argument. And of coursen the connection should be closed in a finally block, or by a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: I fixed it for you, since your answer is helpful. The query must be passed to prepareStatement(), not to executeUpdate(). And of course, the parameters must be set before calling executeUpdate().